# Which rifle will hurt the shoulder more and why?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws

I have this: Two identical bullets are fired one by a light rifle and another by a heavy rifle with the same force. Which rifle will hurt the shoulder more and why?

and my thoughts about the answer seem to contradict each other.

Using the fact that acceleration is inversely proportional to the mass of a body (Newton's second law of motion F=ma), the lighter rifle as a result will hurt more.

but

since the bullets are identical i.e., of the same mass (?) and the forces are also equal, this means that they possess the same acceleration (from the same equation, F=ma).

But I still think the first reason seems more logical and though I am utterly confused.
Please correct me and help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first intuition is correct, the lighter rifle will undergo greater acceleration, and likely hurt more due to the greater recoil. In both cases, total momentum of the system remains the same at 0. The total energy of the system will be the energy released by the bullet being fired.

Your second intuition is actually incorrect, the bullet will leave the heavier gun faster. Since total momentum remains the same in both cases, and the one gun is heavier, it will have lower recoil velocity. It also has lower kinetic energy than the lighter gun, since KE is proportional to the *square* of the velocity. The kinetic energy that's not in the heavier gun must be in the bullet, and since the mass of the bullets are identical, this translates into greater velocity. Your error is in thinking that F remains the same in both situations, which is not the case. As the lighter gun recoils more, it makes more space for the expanding gases in the barrel, imparting less force to the bullet.

You can also think of an extreme case where you fire a bullet from a gun with the same mass as the bullet itself. Now both the gun and bullet shoot off in opposite directions with equal magnitude of velocity when the trigger is pulled. In this cases of a very light gun, the recoil has very large kinetic energy, and you're effectively shooting yourself - it's going to hurt.

Comment: the second paragraph has a mistake. The bullet's change in kinetic energy is W=Fdx, the F is the same, and dx is, at the best, smaller in the light pistol case because it recoils faster, so the kinetic energy of the bullet and thus the bullet's speed must be the same or smaller for the lighter rifle. Another way to see it is that the momentum of the bullet is p=f dt

Comment: @Wolphramjonny If you bolt the gun to an immovable wall (so it behaves as a gun with infinite mass), all the energy contained in the cartridge goes into the bullet and none into the gun, so the bullet leaves the heavier gun faster. You are incorrect that F is the same - the force of the expanding gas in the barrel on the bullet is less for the lighter gun, since that expanding gas is also causing more recoil in the lighter gun. It's like compressing a spring with both hands, and then releasing only one hand compared to releasing both hands.

Comment: but the assumption was that F is the same, not that the total energy of the system was the same (which perhaps would be more realistic)

Comment: @Wolphramjonny Well, that assumption that F is the same is doesn't really have any justification, so it's not a good place to start. We know for sure that the only energy in this system comes from the chemical energy in the cartridge, so fixing E is the only way to go.

Comment: If you changed the assumtion it would be good to clarify it in your answer. Plus if the gun was made with a spring the velocity of the bullet will be smaller the smaller the mass of the rifle, assuming same spring size and k

Comment: @Wolphramjonny Added to the answer. You're correct about the spring-powered gun - in fact, it makes no difference whatsoever if the gun is powered by chemical propellants, a spring, or is an electromagnetic railgun. The lighter gun recoils more and has lower muzzle velocity, all other things being equal.