# Calculate the speed of a rifle bullet as a result of shooting a bullet, should we use momentum or kinetic energy?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, projectile

Say a rifle fires a bullet. We know the mass of the bullet, the velocity of the bullet (upon exiting the barrel) and the mass of the rifle. The rifle shoots hanging from a string, and we want an estimate of the velocity of the rifle going in the opposite direction of the bullet.

Newton's third law, we can assume that the momentum of the system is preserved and that the kinetic energy is preserved.

However, we can very different results using momentum or kinetic energy. Say we have a rifle bullet going at 850 m/s at some 4 grams, with the rifle being 3 kg.

With momentum, I get 1.13 m/s for the rifle.

With energy, I get 31 m/s.

I know that we can always assume conservation of momentum is true, whereas with kinetic energy, there can be significant heat loss.

I thought that I remembered how this works, but considering how it has been more than 20 years since I solved these types of questions, I'm afraid I don't remember what to use here.

Should we use conservation of momentum or energy to estimate this?

And why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which rifle will hurt the shoulder more and why?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/440717/)

Comment: @ParthSareen Thank you. I don't think it does, it doesn't appear to address my misunderstanding about momentum vs. kinetic energy directly. The question is also phrased in a convoluted manner that doesn't easily adapt to understanding this question, I think.

Answer (score 7):

Momentum is always conserved. Kinetic Energy is not.

But more importantly, how did you use energy conservation in this problem? The initial kinetic energy is 0, so then the final kinetic energy would be 0 too? Unless you accounted for the energy of the gunpowder?

If you set the rifle KE to the bullet KE, that's actually not how you're supposed to set up energy conservation problems, it's $E_i = E_f$.

Comment: What are your suffixes i and f here? And assuming the energy is perfectly transferred (no heat loss), why can't I set rifle KE to bullet KE? I understand there is actual heat loss as I mentioned initially, and that this might prevent this. But beyond that, why can't I set these equal to each other?

Comment: @AlphaCentauri *i* and *f* are standard abbreviations for "initial" and "final". You can't se rifle KE to bullet KE because that's not how energy conservation works. Energy before the event is equal to the energy after the event; before the event KE = 0; after it is evidently not 0.

Comment: @AlphaCentauri there simply is no way for an isolated collision between a bullet rifle to conserve kinetic energy, due to the fact that they **must** conserve momentum. Try as much as you wish! What this tells us is that it's necessary for some of the kinetic energy to get transferred to heat energy in the constituent molecules.

Comment: @AlphaCentauri You might then ask, what if there wasn't a way for the atoms to accept that energy, like if the collision were between two point particles? In that case the extra energy would get released as a photon, as is common in particle physics collisions.

Comment: You cannot set rifle KE to bullet KE because there is no law in physics that constraints rifle KE to be equal to bullet KE? If you think conservation of energy allows you to do that, then that is not so : conservation of energy only requires the gunpowder energy to be equal to the total KE of bullet + rifle , plus the heat/sound/light energies.

Answer (score 1):

Energy conservation law could go in this task like this :
$$ \eta~\Phi ~m_{~\text{powder}} = K_B + K_R \tag 1$$

$\Phi$ is gunpowder energy release rate [which is about](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gunpowder) $3~\text{kJ/g}$ (this depends on powder used), $m_{~\text{powder}}$ - grams of gunpowder in the rifle cartridge (depends on cartridge), $~~\eta$ - gun effectiveness, i.e. how much gunpowder energy goes into mechanical energy which accelerates the bullet+rifle system. The rest energy of fire ($1-\eta$) goes into "parasitic" dissipation like heat, sound, light splash, gas acceleration and etc. $K_B$ is kinetic energy of bullet and $K_R$ - kinetic energy of rifle, directed backwards.

You know bullet kinetic energy, which is about $1.4~\text{kJ}$, $K_R$ is unknown variable which has to be solved for in (1) equation. You must have gun detailed specification to know how much grams of gunpowder goes into rifle cartridge, for example some references gives that Winchester W748 cartridge stores $1.5 g$ of gunpowder. However your task does not specify the gun and cartridge properties, so it can be different.

And the last, the biggest problem of all,- specification of gun effectiveness $\eta$, if you know it - plug into formula and you will get an approximate answer which will be energy conservation law-based.

Answer (score 1):

> ... should we use momentum or kinetic energy ?

Use conservation of momentum. Although the energy released from the gunpowder in the bullet's cartridge gives kinetic energy to both the bullet and the gun (and some energy goes into heat and sound), there is no reason why the kinetic energy of the bullet and the gun have to be equal after the shot is fired. If they were, then a golfer would be knocked off their feet every time they hit a ball off the tee.